# Calculation of a total number of "0" positions between "1" positions in a vector int[]

Tags: java, algorithm, vector

There is a vector of 1 and 0:

```
int[] vec = new int[6]{0,1,0,0,1,0};
```

I need to calculate total number of "0" positions between "1" positions. For instance, if `<0,1,0,0,1,0>` then the answer is 2. However, the problem is that the vector may contain the following values:

```
int[] vec = new int[6]{0,1,0,0,0,0};  // the answer is 0
```

or

```
int[] vec = new int[6]{1,0,0,1,0,1};  / the answer is 3
```

So far, I just made a simple algorithm for the 1st case (`<0,1,0,0,1,0>`).

```
    int start = 0, end = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<vec.length; i++)
    {
        if (vec[i] == 1 && start == 0)
            start = i;

        if (vec[i] == 1 && start != 0)
            end = i;
    }
    int result = end - start - 1;
```

I need some help with the development of more generic algorithm that could handle all the above-mentioned cases.

Comment: @keyser: let's better say "calculate"

Comment: Just add to the total sum whenever you encounter a "1" beyond the first one.

Comment: @keyser: but what about the "start" position?

Comment: Then start at -1. If you end up with -1 or 0, then you didn't have two 1's.

Comment: I was more thinking about a general solution rather than your code. However, I think Eran's answer is simpler since it doesn't require you to keep track of anything (after finding your endpoints)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the array from both ends to find the first and last `1`. Then, if you found both, count the `0`s between them.

```
int start = -1;
int end = vec.length;
int i = 0;
int j = vec.length-1;
while (i < j) {
    if (vec[i] == 1 && start < 0)
        start = i;
    i++;
    if (vec[j] == 1 && end >= vec.length)
        end = j;
    j--;
    if (start >= 0 && end < vec.length)
        break;
} 
int count = 0;
if (start >= 0 && end < vec.length) {
    for (i = start + 1; i < end; i++) {
        if (vec[i] == 0)
            count++;
    }
}
```

It can probably be optimized into a single loop.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, initially I thought you wanted to count the number of segments rather than the actual number of zeroes.

You can count all the zeroes after the first one (`n`), keeping track of the number of zeroes since the last one seen (`m`). Then when you reach the end of the vector, your count of `n` is `m` zeroes too high.

```
int count = 0;
int zeroesSinceLastOne = 0;
bool firstOneSeen = false;

for(int i = 0, n = vector.size(); i < n; ++i)
{
    while(!firstOneSeen && vector[i] == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }
    firstOneSeen = true;

    if(vector[i] == 0)
    {
        ++count; 
        ++zeroesSinceLastOne;
    }
    else
    {
        zeroesSinceLast = 0;
    }
}

return count - zeroesSinceLastOnce;
```

*Disclaimer:* untested. May give the wrong number or kill your cat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this algo:

```
startIndex = -1;
endIndex = -1;
for i from 1 to vec.length():
   if( 1 == vec[i])
       startIndex = i
       break;
for i from vec.length() to 1:
   if( 1 == vec[i])
       endIndex = i
       break;
ans = endIndex - startIndex - no_of_ones_in_between
```